# Javascript OOPS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Hi i am using object oriented javascript and using jquery animations . i am new in OOP Javascript. I am getting a error "TypeError: this.setUpAd is not a function" . I am trying to call a button event but getting this error.

```
init: function () {
        this.mainContainer = '#' + this.config.mainContainer;
        this.intro_image = '#' + this.config.intro_image;
        this.text1 = '#' + this.config.text1;
        this.text2 = '#' + this.config.text2;
        this.text3 = '#' + this.config.text3;


        $("#mainContainer").click(function () {
            this.setUpAd();
        });
    },


    bannerAnimation: function () {

        //Jquery Animation
        var text1 = this.text1;
        var text2 = this.text2;
        var text3 = this.text3;
        $(this.intro_image).animate({ width: "120px",
            height: "140px"
        }, 1000);
        $(text1).animate({ left: "20" }, 500, function () {
            $(text1).animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
            $("#btn2").animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(text2).animate({ left: "20" }, 500, function () {
                $(text3).animate({ left: "20" }, 500, function () {
                    $(text3).animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
                });
                $(text2).animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
            });
        }, 1000);
    },
    // Handle Ad Setup



    setUpAd: function() {
  this.d("click").addEventListener('click', function (e) { EB.clickthrough(); }, false);

}
```

Or is there any better way to write the button click code. Thanks

Comment: Declare `setUpAd` function above `init`. add call directly without using `this` reference. i.e.  `setUpAd();` instead of `this.setUpAd();`

Comment: i am getting this error now 
ReferenceError: setUpAd is not defined

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming with Java? Why the potentially misleading [tag:java] tag attached to the question?

Comment: And why the [tag:php] tag? Am I missing something here?

Comment: sorry guys i am new here i was just thinking it belongs to the basic programming concepts so i tagged php n java

Comment: Don't do that. Please only use relevant tags, otherwise you'll be considered "tag spamming".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of your click-handler, `this` is not same as in your `init()` function.

You could assign the value to a variable and use that:

```
init: function () {
    var me = this;

    this.mainContainer = '#' + this.config.mainContainer;
    this.intro_image = '#' + this.config.intro_image;
    this.text1 = '#' + this.config.text1;
    this.text2 = '#' + this.config.text2;
    this.text3 = '#' + this.config.text3;

    $("#mainContainer").click(function () {
        me.setUpAd();
    });
},
```

Comment: thanks jeroren it solves my problem:)